# How to add a custom keybindings to a specified layer of Spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

For example, I want to bind `M .` to `godef-jump`, how can I do this for only the go layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode`. Just set the keybinding for go-mode

Comment: Is there a convention on where or which file to write the code？

Comment: I am not sure which is the "convention" way. For me, I just create my private layer such as "goplus" and add it to packages.el and add "go" layer to layers.el